# GEt data from array object

Tags: php

Hi i'm new to PHP and have below problem. i have written below codes to add data in to the array, now i need to see the added data, please tell me how to do it.

```
class ShoppingCart
{
private $items = array();
private $n_items = 0;
function addItem( Item $item )
{
 $this->items[] = $item;
$this->n_items = $this->n_items + 1;
//print_r (array_values($this->items));
echo "item $this->items added sussesfully";
}
}
```

and

```
class Item {
protected $name;
protected $price;

public function __construct($name, $price) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->price = $price;
}

public function getName() {
    echo "item is $this->name";
    return $this->name;
}

public function getPrice() {
    return $this->price;
}

}
```

and

```
require_once('AddingMachine.php');
require_once('item.php');

//$arrayofnumbers = array(100,200);

$objectname = new ShoppingCart();
$objectname->addItem(new Item('My Super Cool Toy', 10.99));
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "see the added data"?

Answer (score 0):

Since `$items` is a private property you will need to create a new method on the `ShoppingCart` class

```
public function getItems()
{
    return $this->items;
}
```

And then retrieve the `$items` array by calling the new method

```
$objectname = new ShoppingCart();
$items = $objectname->getItems();

var_dump($items);
```